# How can I get property values from an injected model in _Layout shared view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I get the following error due this [line](https://github.com/JorgeDLG/ClaveSol/blob/6a58f946a253b3b27fb2ac60cfc1c537ce728f66/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L39):

```
@inject ClaveSol.Models.Category category

...

@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Category>)category)
{
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-asp-area="" asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </a>
}
```

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ClaveSol.Models.Category' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ClaveSol.Models.Category]'.
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__38_1() in _Layout.cshtml, line 39
```

I was trying to pass `Category` model to my `_Layout.cshtml` view and iterate over it's Name property values.
I followed [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/view-injection-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) tuto. and I added the `(IEnumerable)` conversion([here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1329430.aspx?error%20CS1579%20foreach%20statement%20cannot%20operate%20on%20variables%20of%20type%20object%20because%20object%20does%20not%20contain%20a%20public%20definition%20for%20GetEnumerator%20)) in the foreach because I get `CS1579 error`.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Wouldn't there be another way to get the Category model without using injection? Or is it the best way for this partial view?

Comment: ClaveSol.Models.Category category  change it to IEnumerable<ClaveSol.Models.Category> category and var item in (IEnumerable<Category>)category to var item in category. Hope it should work

Comment: @user13422309 item returns null in foreach

Answer (score 1):

You inject the `ClaveSol.Models.Category` into view and it's an `class`. and you pass the an object to [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) instead of list of objects.

If your model has one object don't use `foreach` and replace your code with :

```
@inject ClaveSol.Models.Category category


<a class="dropdown-item" asp-asp-area="" asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)//<--Note THIS
</a>
```

Or if your model is a list you must change the `@inject` model to this

```
@inject List<ClaveSol.Models.Category> category
```

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) maybe helpful for you

**Update**

Create an interface like this

```cs
public interface ICategoryService
{
    List<Category> GetAllCategories();
}
```

Create an class like this

```cs
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    private readonly ClaveSolDbContext  _dbContext;

    public CategoryService(ClaveSolDbContext  dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public List<Category> GetAllCategories()
    {
        return _dbContext.Category.ToList();
    }
}
```

Register `ICategoryService` into **DI** in `ConfigureService` method in `Startup.cs`  class

```cs
service.AddScoped<ICategoryService,CategoryService>();
```

Then inject `ICategoryService` in your layout

```
@inject ICategoryService categoryService
```

Finally call `GetAllCategories` in `foreach`

```cs
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Category>)categoryService.GetAllCategories())
{
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-asp-area="" asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </a>
}
```

Comment: my model category has more than 1 objects with it's name property.
I tried `inject List<ClaveSol.Models.Category> category` and added for it `services.AddTransient<List<Category>>();` in startup.cs
but the item in foreach returns null.

Comment: @dlag You only register `services.AddTransient<List<Category>>();` into **DI**. you must register a default value for `services.AddTransient<List<Category>>();`. see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-injection)

Comment: I get error CS0246 when I insert `@model IEnumerable<ToDoItem>`.
And later in the tuto they inserts `services.AddTransient<IToDoItemRepository, ToDoItemRepository>();` in the ConfigureServices() , but I wouldn't like having to modify my Category model, only iterate over objects like in any other view.

Comment: I get CS0246 error on startup.cs when I insert `services.AddScoped<ICategoryService,CategoryService>();` for the class and the interface.
`using ClaveSol.Models;` says unecessary.

Comment: @dlag Do you add namespace of `ICategoryService` in `startup.cs` ?

Comment: I put it interface & class on controllers, I was adding the wrong nspace.
I still have the same error anyway.
[Line error](https://github.com/JorgeDLG/ClaveSol/blob/84f9dc3c0d536cf15a94673d6772242c8152537d/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L13).

Comment: @dlag Add `@using ClaveSol.Controllers;` in top of `_Layout`. or replace `@inject ICategoryService categoryService` to `@inject ClaveSol.Controllers.ICategoryService categoryService`

Comment: I have one question. Why you inject the interface instead of Category model? (by convention, simplicity or directly you can't do it with the model?)